# How to mock std::localtime in cpp

Tags: c++, googletest

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
tm *currentTime = localtime(&now);
HelperClass helper({(uint8_t)currentTime->tm_mday,(uint8_t)(1+ currentTime->tm_mon),
                    (uint16_t)(currentTime->tm_year+1900),
                    (uint8_t)currentTime->tm_hour,
                    (uint8_t)currentTime->tm_min,(uint8_t)currentTime->tm_sec});
```

And output of this I need to test in gtest.
Do anyone know how to mock it for gtest?

Comment: You cannot mock free functions, you have to wrap them in class.

Comment: What do you mean "mock" it? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Everytime local time will change and hence, the testcase expectation should also change. For which I want to kind of create a mock method or stub. So localtime can take value I intended to send and not the system time.

Comment: @Jarod42 How to wrap them in class, can you briefly explain it?